# Yum doesn't work

Tags: centos, software-installation, yum

Today I try to list installed php packages with yum but when I run "yum list php*". I have got a strange error "There was a problem importing one of the Python modules required to run yum. The error leading to this problem was", I google it and there is a lot of information about that and try few "fixes" but they doesn't work. I try "yum clean all" as in other cases but it doesn't work.

You can see the problem at this screenshot.
[image: Yum doesn't work and this is the problem]

So can anybody helps me? I'm using CentOS 6.5 x86_64.

Best regards,
George!

Comment: So what does the Faq wiki say?

Comment: If I was found something about this there this question would be meaningless.

Yesterday I try to install AceStream and I use "cp" command with "-a" and now I see that folder /usr was with changed Owner and Group. Now I chown them recursively to root:root and after reboot there are two options for my system - It'll work or It'll not work :)

Answer (score 3):

In case rpm subsystem works, you may consider to do following:
Verify *yum* and *rpm-python* packages

```
rpm -v --verify rpm-python
rpm -v --verify yum
```

You may try to restore permissions and owner for installed packages

like [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/reset-rhel-centos-fedora-package-file-permission.html) and [here](https://superuser.com/a/315856/312809) with:

```
rpm --setugids {packagename}
rpm --setperms {packagename}
```

Or reinstall manually from mirror, like so:

```
rpm -i --force http://mirror.centos.org/centos-6/6.5/os/x86_64/Packages/rpm-python-4.8.0-37.el6.x86_64.rpm
```